# Notification not working (htc wildfire)

Tags: android, notificationmanager

I am trying to play a sound, and flash the backlight of android phone using notification manager. I have used the following code. All the required permissions are there in the manifest file. But I am not sure why this is not giving any notification in emulator or in the device (htc wildfire). If you know any feasible solution please let me know

```
XYNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int NOTFICATION_ID = 1331;
        Notification notifyDetails = new Notification();
        notifyDetails.icon = R.drawable.icon12;
        notifyDetails.tickerText = "Message Received!!!";
        notifyDetails.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        notifyDetails.vibrate = new long[] {0,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000}; //vibrate;

        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, XYReceiverAppActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        CharSequence contentTitle = "XYs Notification";
        CharSequence contentText = "Get back to XY HOME screen by clicking me";


        notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, pIntent);

        Uri xysound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+ "soundxy");

        notifyDetails.ledARGB = Color.BLUE;
        notifyDetails.ledOnMS = 10000;
        notifyDetails.ledOffMS = 1000;
        notifyDetails.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notifyDetails.sound =  xysound;



        XYNotificationManager.notify(NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
```

The device is not vibrating neither is there any sound alert. LED light is same. how do I send the notification?

Comment: there is a persistent status bar icon. but nothing else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code I use in one of my programs, it always worked...

```
        int icon = R.drawable.alerte;
        CharSequence tickerText = getString(R.string.lieuproche);
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                ActivityToLaunch.class);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(
                MainActivity.this,
                "title",
                "action", PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this.getBaseContext(), 0, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Setsuki. Can you please tell me what is "notificationShowing" ???

Comment: Oops, sorry about that one, a piece of code I should have deleted.
It's just a boolean to know if I already have a notification, I needed it for later, it's not important.

Comment: Let me know if it changed anything

Comment: Hey Setsuki... sorry for the delay in reply.... but it is working properly except one thing.... The sound I assigned for the notification plays properly in emulator but in device the default text message sound overrides the notification sound. As I have assigned Insistent flag it should be playing the sound till user touches the status bar icon. but it only plays for 2 seconds and then the default sound and vibration takes over. Can you please suggest something ?